# Solve a recurrence relation with indices far away

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> I am trying to solve the following recurrence relation in two variables of the function $f(x,y)$ where $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, $y\geq 0$:
> $$f(m,n)=f(m-2^n,n-1)+f(m+2^n,n-1)+f(m,n-1)$$

where the base case values are $f(0,0)=f(1,0)=f(-1,0)=1$ and $f(i,0)=0$ for $i\notin \{0,\pm 1\}$.

I was planning on using a bivariate generating function but that lead me anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: This is essentially a recurrence relation on the sequences $\{f(m,n)\}_m$.